# ruby remove duplicates from multidimensional array

Tags: ruby, arrays, multidimensional-array, iteration, uniq

Trying to create every permutation of a  set of names and place them into a multi-dimensional array as pairs and then remove any duplicates. The problem I am having is iterating over the array, comparing the two values and deleting that array if they are the same.

```
names = ["Bob", "Dave", "Clive"]
names2 = names.repeated_combination(2).to_a
[["Bob", "Bob"], ["Bob", "Dave"], ["Bob", "Clive"], ["Dave", "Dave"], ["Dave", "Clive"],     ["Clive", "Clive"]]
```

## This should return a unique set of multidimensional arrays

```
names2.each { |x| x.delete_if { |y| y.slice(0) == y.slice(1) }}
```

But it returns the same array as before with the duplicates.
I tried appending 'uniq' in several places but that made no difference.

Comment: just mention the expected output ... also Do you want to remove `["Bob", "Bob"]` as duplicates ?

Comment: why not trying only `names.combination(2).to_a` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do :

```
names = ["Bob", "Dave", "Clive"]
names.combination(2).to_a
# => [["Bob", "Dave"], ["Bob", "Clive"], ["Dave", "Clive"]]
```

and to correct your code :-

```
non_uniq_comb = names.repeated_combination(2).reject { |a,b| a == b }
# => [["Bob", "Dave"], ["Bob", "Clive"], ["Dave", "Clive"]]
```

Comment: Yeah thanks, removed the need for extra lines to sort duplicates out!

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to remove arrays with the same names:

```
(names2.map { |n| n if n[0] != n[1]}).compact
```